# Change the different character with different color using Native JS

Tags: javascript

I have a table below which is returned by AJAX into HTML:

```
No.   Item      Group 
1     Apple        ❶ 
2     Cow          ❸
3     Iron         ❷
4     Banana       ❶
5     Horse        ❸
6     Aluminum     ❷
7     etc..
8     etc
...
200 Items++
```

I want to mark the character in the Group column with colors:
❶ = Green, ❷ = Red, ❸ = Blue

What is the simplest way to do that? I am looking for kind of "search and color it" method using native JS solution. 
Pls suggest, thanks.

Comment: Please show the actual HTML markup, not some visual abstraction.

Comment: How do you know which group is which colour, do you have a table/array/dictionary for the mapping?

Comment: ❶ , ❷ , ❸ are unicode character, are u able to see the different number in the black dot? Can't we differentiate it using JS?

Comment: Simply create a class with group number and applied on colimn based on group value

Comment: @P.Lau Of course we can differentiate them using JS, what I'm asking in what data format you have the color mapping. JS won't understand the natural language "*❶ = Green, ❷ = Red, ❸ = Blue*". You need something like `{"❶": "#0F0", "❷": "#F00", "❸": "#00F"}` (JSON symbol to rgb string)

Comment: Hi. I manage to solve it myself oredi using loop the  <span class ="row['group']"> in php page then control it by CSS. Anyway thanks for your attention.